# update_post_meta and update_field not working without any error received

Tags: php, wordpress, api, insert-update

I am working with a wordpress site that imports all data from API to the site automatically via cron job. However, I'm now on the part of saving the field data from the API. The problem is update_post_meta and update_fields are both not working.

I already tried interchanging between the two methods of saving but both doesn't work. No error prompts and no results as well (which is pretty weird for me). I checked the built-in plugin of the site and it uses update_post_meta.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_properties_from_api','get_properties_from_api');
add_action('wp_ajax_get_properties_from_api','get_properties_from_api')
    function  get_properties_from_api(){

        $file = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/report.txt';
        $current_page=(! empty($_POST['current_page'])) ? $_POST['current_page'] : 1;
        $properties = [];

        $results = wp_remote_retrieve_body(wp_remote_get('https://www.realestateview.com.au/listing_api?rm=search&company=castlemain&code=29GKRRSgkVdQVM&CID=5813&json=1&ptr=r&con=S&portalview=residential&rn=1&pg='. $current_page));

        file_put_contents($file, "Current page: ". $current_page. "\n\n", FILE_APPEND);

        $results=json_decode($results, true);

        if(!is_array($results['Listings']) || empty($results['Listings'])){
            return false;
        }

        $properties[]=$results;
        foreach($properties[0] as $property){
            $property_slug = sanitize_title($property->TitleNoHTML, '-', $property->OrderID);

            $inserted_property = wp_insert_post([
                'post_name' => $property_slug,
                'post_title' => $property->TitleNoHTML,
                'post_type' => 'property', 
                'post_status' => 'publish',
            ]);

            if(is_wp_error($inserted_property)){
                continue;
            }
            $fillable=[
            //Basic information
            get_the_title($inserted_property) => 'TitleNoHTML',
            'REAL_HOMES_property_price'  => 'PriceText',
            'REAL_HOMES_property_size' => 'LandSizeText',
            'REAL_HOMES_property_bedrooms' => 'BedroomsCount',
            'REAL_HOMES_property_bathrooms' => 'BathroomsCount',
            'REAL_HOMES_property_garage' => 'LockUpGaragesCount',
            'REAL_HOMES_featured' => 'FeaturedProperty',
            //$this->REAL_HOMES_property_id = 
            //$this->REAL_HOMES_property_year_built =

            //Location on Map
            'REAL_HOMES_property_address' => 'AddressText',
            'REAL_HOMES_property_location' => 'Suburb',
            'REAL_HOMES_property_map' => 'DisplayTrueAddress',

            //Gallery
            'REAL_HOMES_property_images' => 'PhotoOriginalURL',

            //Floor Plans

            //$this->inspiry_floor_plan_name =
            'inspiry_floor_plan_price' => 'PriceText',
            //$this->inspiry_floor_plan_price_postfix =
            // $this->inspiry_floor_plan_size =
            // $this->inspiry_floor_plan_size_postfix = 
            'inspiry_floor_plan_bedrooms' => 'BedroomsCount',
            'inspiry_floor_plan_bathrooms' =>'BathroomsCount',
            // $this->inspiry_floor_plan_descr = 
            'inspiry_floor_plan_image' => 'FloorplanThumbURL',

            //Property Video
            'inspiry_video_group_image' => 'PhotoThumbURL',
            //$this->inspiry_video_group_title = 
            'inspiry_video_group_url' => 'VideoURL',

            //DEPRECATED FIELDS
            // $this->REAL_HOMES_360_virtual_tour =
            // $this->REAL_HOMES_tour_video_url_divider =
            // $this->REAL_HOMES_tour_video_url =
            // $this->REAL_HOMES_tour_video_image =

            //Agent
            //$this->REAL_HOMES_agent_display_option =
            'REAL_HOMES_agents' => 'ContactAgentName',

            //Energy Performance
            // $this->REAL_HOMES_energy_class  =
            // $this->REAL_HOMES_energy_performance =
            // $this->REAL_HOMES_epc_current_rating =
            // $this->REAL_HOMES_epc_potential_rating =

            //Misc
            // $this->REAL_HOMES_sticky =
            // $this->inspiry_property_label =
            // $this->inspiry_property_label_color =

            // $this->REAL_HOMES_attachments =

            'inspiry_property_owner_name' => 'ClientName',
            //$this->inspiry_property_owner_contact = 
            'inspiry_property_owner_address' => 'ClientAddress',
            // $this->REAL_HOMES_property_private_note =
            // $this->inspiry_message_to_reviewer =

            //Homepage slider
            // $this->REAL_HOMES_add_in_slider = 
            // $this->REAL_HOMES_slider_image =
            // $this->REAL_HOMES_page_banner_image =

            //Additional fields
            'inspiry_InspectionDateandStartTime' => 'ISOInspectionStart',
            'inspiry_InspectionDateandFinishTime' => 'ISOInspectionFinish',             
            ];
            foreach($fillable as $key => $TitleNoHTML){
                update_post_meta($inserted_property, $key, $property->$TitleNoHTML);

            }
        }


        $current_page = $current_page + 1;
        wp_remote_post(admin_url('admin-ajax.php?action=get_properties_from_api'), [
            'blocking' => false,
            'sslverify' => false,
            'body' => [
                'current_page' => $current_page
            ]
        ]);

What I'm already expecting is it should be already save some data, if not, it should produce an error but for some weird reason, there isn't. I tried to var_dump some variables and I think it should be working. Would anyone be able to help me find out where I gone wrong?
```

Comment: Is this a real cron or a plugin that does a cron? A real cron job wouldn't know the wordpress functions and you will need to use `wget` instead of running a php script.

Comment: I'm trying to make a real cron without plugin. Could you give me pointers on how I could achieve it? I'm quite new with wordpress and this task is pretty nerve-wracking

Answer (score 0):

In order to replace the Wordpress cron with a real cron job you will need to set a cron job which will fetch data from a webpage using `wget`. First you will need to create a `Wordpress` page which will contain your `PHP` code then fetch the content with cron using `wget`.

The real cron job command will look like this:

`wget -q -O - http://yourdomain.com/your_cron_page >/dev/null 2>&1`

`-q` tells `wget` to operate quietly (ie. to not output the usual status information)

`-O /dev/null` tells it to output to `/dev/null`

Keep in mind that everyone can access this page so you might want to set some restrictions.

Comment: does that mean what I'm trying to do can be done via default wordpress cron job? can the default one update or add info on custom fields?

Comment: yeah, there are several plugins that can do that or link your cron to `wp-cron.php`. More info here: https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-view-and-control-wordpress-cron-jobs/